# Question marked as duplicate of a question that has no answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How do I allow multiple users to connect to my H2 database simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26743992/4957418) is marked as a duplicate of [How do I share an H2 database over a peer-to-peer network?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26667249/4957418) with the comment:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

Unfortunately, the second question *does not* have any answers (visible to me), but only a comment thread (50+ comments).

It doesn't look like like an exact duplicate either.

What is the protocol to deal with a mess like this?

Comment: 50+ comments... Judging by the title along with comments, looks to me like it's too broad..?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Closing as a duplicate of a question which has no answers is only possible if the user posted both the question and the duplicate target, which is what happened here. There are no deleted answers on either question presently.

I agree that these questions, while about the same technology, do not look like duplicates to me. However, I know very little on the topic they ask, so I will defer reopening to experts on the topic with reopen privileges.

One thing you might consider is editing the closed question to make it better, and possibly reduce the chances others will think it is a duplicate. Once a closed question is edited, it will be added to the reopen review queue where those with reopen privileges will see it and vote on reopening it.

**Update:**

Apparently editing will only add it to the reopen queue once, and only if edited with 5 days from being closed, while the questions says "on hold".

Comment: I wasn't aware that edited questions get placed on the reopen review queue.

Comment: FYI edits only put the question into the queue if the edit was done in the first 14 days since it was closed.  After that time only a reopen vote will add it to the queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver Also, if I remember right, that only happens once. So, make that first edit the best possible edit for the best chance at getting it reopened.

Comment: @BoogaRoo I cannot confirm but that sounds logical.

Comment: @NathanOliver: *5 days. Coincides with the duration it's called "on hold"; after that it's just closed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy So it is.  Not sure why I though it was 2 weeks.

Comment: Some people just votedown the answer or question without looking carefully at question or answer or without giving any comment. I faced myself many questions that have been marked duplicate but when I looked at the duplicate question it was another question or the answer was not correct or had no answer at all.